# Instantiation of function template with variadic parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Suppose say I have this code:

```
template<int... Us>
struct Matrix{};

template<int... U1, int... U2>
auto compute(Matrix<U1...>, Matrix<U2...>){return 0;}

Matrix<1> a; Matrix<2,3> b;
Matrix<1,2> c; Matrix<3> d;

int main(){   
    compute(a,b);
    compute(c,d);
    auto fp = &compute<1,2,3>;
    fp(a,b);
    fp(c,d);
}
```

Would the two compute() calls instantiate just one function template i.e. compute<1,2,3> or would there be two different instantiations depending on the arguments?

I wanted to confirm this by taking a function pointer to the particular instantiation and see if I could call the function with the 2 different sets of arguments using the same function pointer but I get the following errors at the line where I call fp(a,b):

> ```
> [x86-64 gcc 8.2 #1] error: could not convert 'a' from
> 'Matrix<#'nontype_argument_pack' not supported by
> dump_expr#<expression error>>' to 'Matrix<#'nontype_argument_pack' not
> supported by dump_expr#<expression error>>'
> ```

Comment: They are obviously not the same, given that a function that takes parameter types `Matrix<1>` and `Matrix<2, 3>` is not the same as a function that takes parameter types `Matrix<1, 2>` and `Matrix<3>`.

Comment: In that case when I do auto fp = &compute<1,2,3> which particular instance gets instantiated given that the compiler doesnt flag that line as an error? Shouldn't the compiler then complain about that?

Comment: I believe that if you write `compute<1, 2, 3>` it assigns all three arguments to `U1` and leaves `U2` empty, but IIRC, the standards text is hard to understand when it comes to issues like this. Just don't do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian.

Comment: Someone just pointed me out to gcc.godbolt.org. I pasted the entire code there and the assembly that is shown side by side clearly pointed out the instantiations. If I had known before, I would have used it and wouldn't have had to ask this question. This is a JFYI for others who havent used that site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameter packs are greedy.

`&compute<1,2,3>` is, in pseudo-code, `&compute< U1={1,2,3}, U2={} >`.

Getting a pointer to the individual computes is annoying.

```
template<class U1s, class U2s>
struct get_computer;
template<int...U1, int...U2>
struct get_computer<std::integer_sequence<int, U1...>, std::integer_sequence<int, U2...>> {
  using compute_type = int(*)(Matrix<U1...>, Matrix<U2...>);
  compute_type operator()() const { return compute; }
};
```

we can then do

```
auto fp1 = get_computer<std::integer_sequence<int, 1>, std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 3>>{}();
auto fp2 = get_computer<std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2>, std::integer_sequence<int, 3>>{}();
```

and `fp1` and `fp2` are different types.

Answer (score 3):

> Would the two `compute()` calls instantiate just one function template i.e. `compute<1,2,3>` or would there be two different instantiations depending on the arguments?

Very differently. The function that is invoked when you write `compute(a, b)` is a function that takes a `Matrix<1>` and a `Matrix<2,3>`. The function that is invoked when you write `compute(c, d)` is a function that takes a `Matrix<1,2>` and a `Matrix<3>`.

But when you write this:

```
auto fp = &compute<1,2,3>;
```

There is no way to say which of `U1...` or `U2...` those values refer to. What every compiler does is slurp all of the arguments into the first pack - so `fp` ends up being a `int(*)(Matrix<1,2,3>, Matrix<>)`. In other words, this version is a function that takes a `Matrix<1,2,3>` and a `Matrix<>`. Which is different from both of the original calls.

And indeed, since the two original calls were calls to *two different functions*, it would not be possible to take a single function pointer to both of them. What you could do instead is construct a function *object* that does the right thing:

```
auto fp = [](auto m1, auto m2){ return compute(m1, m2); };
```

This works (try it), but is a very different kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Barry.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach. No need integer sequence or temporary functor object. Link: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/W4V6gf

```
template<int... V1>
struct Mat1 {
    template<int... V2>
    struct Mat2 {
        using compute_type = int(*)(Matrix<V1...>, Matrix<V2...>);
    };
};

void foo() {
    {
        using compute_type = Mat1<1>::Mat2<2,3>::compute_type;
        compute_type ct = compute;
        ct(a, b);
        //ct(c, d); //This wont compile
    }
    {
        using compute_type = Mat1<1,2>::Mat2<3>::compute_type;
        compute_type ct = compute;
        ct(c, d);
        //ct(a, b);  //This wont compile
    }
}
```

---

**Even More Generic**

```
template<int... Us>
struct Matrix{};

Matrix<1> a; Matrix<2,3> b;
Matrix<1,2> c; Matrix<3> d;

template<int... U1, int... U2>
auto compute(Matrix<U1...>, Matrix<U2...>){return 0;}

template<class Scalar, template<Scalar...> class MatType>
struct VArg {
    template<Scalar... V1>
    struct arg1 {
        using type = MatType<V1...>;
        template<Scalar... V2>
        struct arg2 {
            using type1 = type;
            using type2 = MatType<V2...>;
        };
    };
};

template<class args_gen>
struct compute_type {
    using type = int(*)(typename args_gen::type1, typename args_gen::type2);
};

void foo() {
    using int_matrix_gen = VArg<int, Matrix>;
    {
        using args_ab = int_matrix_gen::arg1<1>::arg2<2,3>;
        compute_type<args_ab>::type cptr = compute;
        cptr(a, b);
        //cptr(c, d); This wont compile
    }
    {
        using args_cd = int_matrix_gen::arg1<1,2>::arg2<3>;
        compute_type<args_cd>::type cptr = compute;
        cptr(c, d);
        //cptr(a, b); This wont compile
    }

}
```

---

Even more Generic'er: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EF6OK9 supporting functions with 3 Matrix arguments.